# For Button action it is showing "MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel 5"

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

> button code

```
  <button type="submit" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" href="{{route('regi') }}" class="btn">Sign up!</button>
```

> route

```
Route::get('regi', array('as' => 'regi', 'uses' => function()
{
   return view('register');
}));
```

> error

```
in RouteCollection.php line 219
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
```

I'm new to Laravel.So I can not figure out error.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What method is your form set to use ?

Comment: Thank you for reply but I did not get  "What method is your form set to use" ?

Comment: what is the 'method' attribute set to on the form in the html ? forms have methods they use, example GET or POST. that exception means you are trying to access a route using the wrong http method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got it.